# Custom wordpress theme images not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm building my first WP theme. My images are linked this way:

`<img src="<?php bloginfo('wp-content/themes/SRPrint'); ?>images/freephone.png" />`

Obviously theme folder called SRPrint and inside it there is an images folder.

Can't understand why images do not show up? I don't know any php so I asume problem is in php code? Images specified through style.css show up ok.

Please help.

Link to test site http://www.designstest.co.uk/

Comment: try the way jothikannan suggested it should work for you

Comment: Hello, check the answer below,no need to put the directory just use 'template_directory' instead of 'wp-content/themes/SRPrint'

Comment: Done that, thank you, but still no luck. It must be something else then. Images are definitely in place, saved and replaced header.php file... run out of ideas what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you must use `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/freephone.png` to get the images in the current theme.

Comment: Sorry, it was not showing the full line of code before. Edited it and as you can see it's the same as you wrote. Or am I missing something?

Comment: use 'template_directory' instead of 'wp-content/themes/SRPrint'

Comment: Hi, use "echo" before bloginfo();

Comment: I found that in your theme only show the image src only without the blog url

Comment: adding echo did not help. I'm not sure what you mean with your last comment.

Comment: I am looking at all sort of tutorials to build this theme and majority of php I have no clue what it means.

Answer (score 1):

See: [bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.jpg" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change all image to `src="
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>
/images/picname.jpg"`